# "work that identify" or "work that identifies"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

Implicitly by `work` I mean plural (several studies). So how should I treat the verb that comes after it?

> Similar to previous work that identifies

Or,

> Similar to previous work that identify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you're using **work** as an uncountable noun (mass noun).  Uncountable nouns are always treated as grammatically singular:

> Similar to previous **work** that **identifies**...

If you use a countable noun in the plural, then the verb changes:

> Similar to previous **studies** that **identify**...

It is possible to use **work** as a countable noun, in the sense of "works of art," for example, in which case you can pluralize both the noun and the verb:

> Similar to previous **works** that **identify**...

This is somewhat unusual and would only be used if you were using the countable **work[s]** in the surrounding text.  In general, when referring to preceding studies or research, the uncountable **work** is used.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, OP's "work" may involve several studies, but it's still a **singular** noun.

> *My favourite **work** by Bach **is** his Toccata & Fugue in D Minor* (a single piece of music)
>    *My favourite **works** by Beethoven **are** his symphonies* (multiple pieces).

---

Hence the choices for OP are...

> *[My analysis is] similar to previous **work** that **identifies** [Africa as the cradle of humanity]*
>    *[My analysis is] similar to previous **works** that **identify** [Africa as the cradle of humanity]*

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other English grammar, the rule for singular-plural verb-subject agreement is pretty straightforward:

*Unless the subject is clearly plural, use the singular conjugation.*

While some words, like "work", have both abstract and concrete meanings, the abstract is considered singular.  Even a general "body of work", which can include many articles, is still singular when considered as a group.

> His **work**, written over the course of a long and distinguished career, **is** considered required reading for students of the field.

If you want to refer to multiple articles, considered *individually*, use the plural:

> His **works**, written over the course of a long and distinguished career, **are** considered required reading for students of the field.

This is the same for the very many similar nouns which have both an abstract/ figurative/ uncountable meaning, and a concrete/ literal/ countable meaning: *philosophy, memory, paper, hair, space, experience, light*, and many, many more.